# Bloco estatico depois do primeiro resultado de um while

Tags: php

Como coloco um bloco estatico de publicidade depois do primeiro resultado de um while em php?

Deixo em baixo o meu while:

```
while($fetch = $get->fetch()){

}
```

Tipo isto:

[image: Resultado do while em php]

Comment: A questão é sobre como formatar os resultados lado a lado ou como construir o código php que traga o resultado estático em 2º lugar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basta usares um **contador**, ou seja quando for a 2 iteração no **while** irá fazer o que for desejado(neste caso irá printar `publicidade`).

E usas o `continue`, para saltar para a próxima iteração.

```
<?php

$contador = 0;

while($fetch = $get->fetch()){
    $contador++;

    echo "conteudo";

    if($contador == 2){
        //Resultado estatico na segunda vez do while
        echo "publicidade";
    }

}
```

Comment: Se utilizar o `continue`, você sempre perderá o segundo registro, pois não será executado o `echo`.

Comment: E como faço para não perder o segundo registo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editado.
Bruno basta testares a condição depois de mostrares o conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma variável de controle. Ficaria algo como

```
$publi = true;
while($fetch = $get->fetch()){
    echo 'conteudo';
    if(publi){
        echo 'publicidade';
        publi = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Confesso que não percebi!

Comment: Considere colocar a pergunta como respondida